# Logstash replace old index

Tags: elasticsearch, command-line, logstash, alias

I'm using logstash to create an elastic index. The steps are :
 1. logstash start
 2. datas are retrieve with a jdbc input plugin 
 3. datas are indexed with an elasticsearch output plugin (with a template includes an alias)
 4. logstash stop

The time, I've got an index call myindex-1 which can be requested with the alias myindex.
The second time, I've got an index call myindex-2 which can be requested with the alias myindex. The first index is now deprecated and I need to delete it just before (or after the step 4).

Do you know how to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

First things first, if you know the deprecated index name, then it's just a question of adding a step 5:

```
curl -XDELETE 'http://localhost:9200/myindex-1'
```

So you'd wrap your logstash run into a script with this additional step - as to my knowledge there is no option for logstash to delete an index, it's simply not its purpose.

But from the way you describe your situation, it seems you're trying to keep the data available during the new index creation, could you elaborate a bit on your use case?

Reason for the asking is that with the current procedure, you're likely to end up with duplicate data (old and new version) during the indexing period.

If there is indeed a need to refresh the data, and assuming that you have an id in the data retrieved from the DB, 
you might consider another approach: configuring 2 elasticsearch outputs in your logstash, 
first one with action set to "delete" targeting the old entry in previous index,
second being your standard create into new index.

Depending on the nature of your data, there might also be other possibilities.

Comment: That's right : I want to keep the data available during the new index creation.

Your solution, with two outputs, is not totally perfect. By exemple : the table contains two rows : 1 and 2. So, the first index contains those two rows. 
Then the row 1 is deleted. The first output delete only the second row, not the first one (because not any more in the DB).

Comment: I don't think you'll find a perfect solution. But regarding my proposal, you'd still keep the old index deletion. The "best" solution will depend on quite a few factors, including: how long does it take to create the new index, the impact of duplicates in the results during the transition for your end users, if there is a value for you to keep the history of the data (in which case my proposal would be really bad), ...

Answer (score 0):

1. Create and populate myindex-2, don't alias it yet
2. Simultaneously add alias to myindex-2 and remove it from myalias-1

REST request for step 2:

```
POST /_aliases
{
    "actions" : [
        { "remove" : { "index" : "myindex-1", "alias" : "myindex" } },
        { "add"    : { "index" : "myindex-2", "alias" : "myindex" } }
    ]
}
```

Documentation [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-aliases.html)